# Aligning div text to right

Tags: html, css

This fiddle center aligns content on page :

http://jsfiddle.net/jbk7e0we/5/

How can this content be aligned so that "Enter Text" appears right aligned with "Big entry for text". I've tried using `align=right` but does not work.

fiddle code :

```
<div class="center">
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; align=right">Enter text</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;"><input type = "text" size = "15"/></div>

    <div style="block"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; align=right">Big entry for text</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;"><input type = "text" size = "15"/></div>
</div>

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
align=right
```

to

```
text-align: right;
```

Example:

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align: right;">Enter text</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;">
    <input type="text" size="15" />
  </div>

  <div style="block"></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align: right;">Big entry for text</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;">
    <input type="text" size="15" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbk7e0we/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your inline style to `text-align:right;` Your code looks as

```
<div class="center">
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:right;">Enter text</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;"><input type = "text" size = "15"/></div>

    <div style="block"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:right;">Big entry for text</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:200px;"><input type = "text" size = "15"/></div>
</div>

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
align=right
```

to:

```
text-align:right
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jbk7e0we/6/)**

Answer (score -1):

Use `text-align: right;` not `align: right`